# typings.json - GitHub vs Registry

Tags: github, npm, dependency-management, http-status-code-403

I'm used to Maven and trying to make sense of package management in this side of the world.

Could some one please help me understand the difference between:

This:

```
"ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438"
  }
```

and this:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
    "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#5c182b9af717f73146399c2485f70f1e2ac0ff2b"
  }
}
```

Is registry pointing to an npm repository?

Is there any difference and which is the preferred method?

I couldn't get registry:dt/es6-shim to work. Kept on getting following error(even though I configured my proxy settings):

> https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/jasmine/tags/2.2.0%2B20160412134438
>   responded with 403, expected it to equal 200